# How to find the observation which has specific character and then remove it?

Tags: stata

I have a variable that contains alphanumeric strings of specific lengths, for example:

Name variable:

```
asdf1
asdg2
zxcv4
asdh3
qwer2
rtyu4
xcvb4
```

I want to delete observations which have `4` as the last character of its name, for instance, `zxcv4`. So, the result is:

Name variable:

```
asdf1
asdg2
asdh3
qwer2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To just `drop` observations where the last character is "4" (rather than any character), do something like:

`drop if substr(strreverse(varname),1,1)=="4"`

Comment: Helpful. Note that `drop if substr(varname, -1, 1) == "4"` is also easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
drop if strpos(name, "4") > 0
```

Comment: This would `drop` if `4` was in any position, not the question.

Comment: Righto, my bad.